# Automation framework for Electron mobile app

Tags: android, electron

I am looking for good test automation framework for Electron based mobile application.

I did some research and found

1. Espresso
2. Appium ( still unclear if it works)

I am concerned since the UI will not be a native Android UI. All our controls will be web controls in a browser which ives in webview.

Looking for suggestions.

Comment: See also `BrowserStack`

Comment: I did not understand your comment. I saw that browser-stack does support Espresso though.

Comment: Sorry, I only know that `BrowserStack` offers test automation through the web browser